# How to show and scale YouTube media in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to use the `WebBrowser` control to play a YouTube video from a link. When I add the link to the WebBrowser control by:

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString("http://www.youtube.com/embed/BppxvEwWffE");
```

then WebBrowser will show the link as text but I want the YouTube video scaled to width and height of WebBrowser and a button "Play video" vertically centered in the control. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation summarized:

- WP7 has no Flash, but HTML5 video
- YouTube in theory can do HTML5 video, but it's still in [test mode](https://www.youtube.com/html5) and not activated by default for all users
- [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462081%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) has possible security implications for your users: "Content loaded from isolated storage or dynamically by using `NavigateToString` has no cross-site restrictions, while content loaded from the network has normal cross-site restrictions."

So while waiting for YouTube to go fully HTML5 you could just send your users to the normal YouTube video page (for example by `webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://youtu.be/BppxvEwWffE"));`). They can then tap the video and the native video player of WP7 opens full screen and plays the video.